# Warning message in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the y label on a stacked bar graph because it seems to be making values that add up to 3 add up to 1 instead.

Here is my data frame:

```
 Morph Choice     Value
1 Orange Orange 1.7333330
2 Orange  Green 1.2666670
3  Green Orange 0.8666667
4  Green  Green 2.1333333
```

Here is my script for generating a stacked bar graph;

```
ggp2M<- ggplot(data = forbargraphMEANS.df,
              aes(x = Morph,
                  y = Value,
                  fill = Choice))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3))
```

which creates this warning message;

```
Warning message:
Removed 4 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

(Without "scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3))" it works but y is 0.00 - 1.00).

I can't figure out how to make it 0-3 rather than 0-1. Also just genuinely confused why it would do 0-1 if 3 of the values in the dataset are more than 1.

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.
Thank you in advance.

N.B. I have created exactly what I wanted with a different dataset that required y to be a percentage.

Comment: With this data and this code, I get no warnings.

Comment: If you want to show the "true" scale of your data try with removing `position="fill"` as "position_fill() stacks bars and standardises each stack to have constant height" of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any warning, but I a little confused about what you exactly want.

```
library(ggplot2)

forbargraphMEANS.df<- data.frame (Morph = c("Orange", "Orange", "Green", "Green"),
                  Choice = c("Orange", "Green", "Orange", "Green"),
                  Value = c(1.7333330, 1.2666670, 0.8666667, 2.1333333)
                  )
forbargraphMEANS.df

ggp2M<- ggplot(data = forbargraphMEANS.df,
              aes(x = Morph,
                  y = Value,
                  fill = Choice))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3))

ggp2M
```

Above is your code, and the output is below
[image: Original code]

If you want it to add up to three, then you can use the following code (remove the `position = "fill"` part)

```
library(ggplot2)

forbargraphMEANS.df<- data.frame (Morph = c("Orange", "Orange", "Green", "Green"),
                  Choice = c("Orange", "Green", "Orange", "Green"),
                  Value = c(1.7333330, 1.2666670, 0.8666667, 2.1333333)
                  )
forbargraphMEANS.df

ggp2M<- ggplot(data = forbargraphMEANS.df,
              aes(x = Morph,
                  y = Value,
                  fill = Choice))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,3))

ggp2M
```

[image: new code]